# iOS App ItunesConnect Validation Error

Tags: ios, api, version, app-store-connect, quickblox

Hi i am using quickblox chat API for my app version 1.0 , it was successfully uploaded in App Store.
In my app version 1.1, i integrated the latest Quickblox iOS SDK, version 1.7.2.

While attempting to upload my app next version binary to iTunes Connect, I get errors when I validate my app. The errors are:

- Your app contains non-public API usage.
- Apps are not permitted to access the UDID and must not use the uniqueIdentifier method of UIDevice.

Is this error because of the Quickblox Latest API ?

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the solution, my third API (Quickblox) was trying to access the Device UDID , which apple doesn't support that, so commented that code and it successfully uploaded in itunesconnect.

Answer (score 1):

According to the developer of Quickblox, access to the UDID is not present anymore since version 1.5.2

> v1.5.2 — May 11, 2013 removed internal access to UDID

The most probable thing is that you have other SDKs that access the UDID, e.g. SDKs that show ads in your app, etc.
You should update all the SDKs and then, if it doesn't help, try leaving one of the SDKs out, and check which one accesses the UDID.

Comment: There are also some Apple tools to search in your app for any api, you should try to use them.